# iphone - debugging on device crashes immediately

Tags: iphone

When I try to debug my app on the iphone device, the splash screen shows and then the app crashes immediately.  If I run the app in the simulator or on the device (not from XCode) it runs fine.  I tried putting a breakpoint in the main method and it doesn't seem to hit it.  There are no logs generated.  ideas?  suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Apple Developer account or have you hacked the phone to develop on it?  If its hacked, that is probably the problem.  There is extra data being passed to the device because of the hack causing it to crash. Not sure if there is an easy work around except paying for a developer account.